# Get #part in URL with PHP/Symfony

Tags: php, url, routes, symfony1

I'm working with Symfony 1.2. I've a view with a list of objects. I can order them, filter them by category, or moving to the next page (there is pagination). Everything is done with AJAX, so I don't have to load all the page again.

What I want to achieve is to have http://urltopage#page=1&order=title&cats=1,2 for example; so the new page is saved in the browser history, and he can paste it to another web.

I haven't found a way to get the #part. I know that's only for the browser but I can't believe I can't get through PHP. I'm sure there is a simple solution I'm missing...

thanks a lot!

Comment: If many many people have told you that you can't get it except through the browser, they are probably right. And you can't.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't get it through PHP because it's never transmitted to the server.

You can, however, get it with JavaScript via `window.location.hash`, then transmit it to the server via AJAX.

Answer (score 2):

The anchor, as you said, is an information that's used by the browser -- and is not sent to the server, when doing a standard HTT GET request.

This means there is no way for your PHP script to get that information...

... unless you try using some Javascript-based magic, like using an Ajax request, sending some additionnal parameter that would contain the value of the anchor, or something like that... but that wouldn't be quite a standard way of doing things, and I would not recommend doing this...

Answer (score 0):

window.location.hash is the only way ("hash"/anchor is client-side only, never ever visible by servers), but nothing forbids you from manipulating the querystring (converting to GET params) or building a FORM using JS and converting to POST params.

That's the basics to build an AJAX javascript request handler/manager. But in the end you should end up building a GET/POST "normal" url to send your request to.

You could also store in a cookie the hash, but again, I wouldn't use it as the way to handle routing or data passing.