# Anchor in routing URL when using Symfony redirect function

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using

```
/**
 * @Route("page/#page")
 */
public function redirectAction()
{
    return $this->redirectToRoute('page');
}
```

But I need to be able to put "#" anchor, but I can't find a way of doing that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use the new [Routing Improvements added in Symfony 3.2](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-routing-improvements). I see you have a symfony2 tag, and it should be in the latest version of Symfony2 as well.

You can't add a anchor to routing annotation, but here's the changes you would need:

```
/**
 * @Route("page")
 *
 */
public function redirectAction()
{
   return $this->redirectToRoute(
      $this->get('router')->generate('page', [
         '_fragment' => 'page'
      ])
   );
}
```

This presumes there is a #page anchor in your page being rendered.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i need to know when the user enters to this route, for example: example.com/#helloWorld, so i can redirect to another page,not just adding the "#" to the end of the route, i'm using sf 2.8 btw.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `redirect` instead of `redirectToRoute`

```
public function yourAction()
{
    return $this->redirect(
         $this->generateUrl('url_route_name') . '#page',
         ['param1' => $param1]
     );
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i need to know when the user enters to this route, for example: http://example.com/#helloWorld, so i can redirect to another page,not just adding the "#" to the end of the route

Answer (score 1):

In a controller you can't get the hash.
Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624119/get-part-in-url-with-php-symfony).

Instead you should change your controller to:

```
/**
 * @Route("page/{page}")
 */
public function redirectAction($page)
{
    return $this->redirectToRoute($page);
}
```

You'd need to adjust the request too.